# Find the top N keys with highest values in Redis

Tags: python, redis

I have Redis database with `user_id: rating` stucture and I need to get the N users with the highest rating (value), like:

```
u_345: 198
u_144: 180
u_267: 179
```

The idea I have: take a list of all the keys, and for each key get its value (`db.mget(db.keys())`), after sort by value and get first N. Is there a better way?

I use the [redis-py](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py) Python library. But the main thing is to get the right algorithm (or a ready-made solution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `ZRANGE` (https://redis.io/commands/zrange/).

Using your dataset, you could use this approach:

```
ZADD ratingindex 198 u_345
ZADD ratingindex 180 u_144
ZADD ratingindex 179 u_267
```

and then, to retrieve 2 (or N) keys with highest values you should use:

`ZRANGE ratingindex 0 1 withscores rev`

This command will retrieve two keys (from 0 to 1) with values (`withscores`) from `ratingindex` ordered from highest to lowest (`rev`).

Finally you just need to adapt this direct commands to redis-py library.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you should follow the pattern of using Sorted Set as a secondary index.

See: https://redis.io/topics/indexes